# How do we respond to the argument of "stupid design"?

Tags: theology, creation

What would counter-arguments from the Jewish perspective be to arguments like the ones in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4238NN8HMgQ) against intelligent design? The basic premise is that humans, Earth, and the universe are, in fact, quite stupidly designed and have many flaws.

I have a few of my own counter-arguments already (namely, that nothing is without flaw except for God, and thus no matter how we were created there would be some flaws — all things considered, life is far more miraculous and intelligently designed than not), but I am curious what we can put together here.

Comment: We don't know the purpose of creation, so saying the design is bad is a bit superfluous. There are also problems of language like "good and bad design" and the entire concept of design in general.

Comment: Who says that "intelligent design" is what Jews believe?

Comment: I encourage answers to clarify how their response is "from the Jewish perspective".

Comment: @Daniel Elaborate...?

Answer (score 6):

I once heard the following from Rav Aharon Lopiansky.  He basically said that any such suggestion of "If G-d really made the world, it should have been like such and such" is making the assumption that when G-d creates a world, He does it in exactly such a way.  Saying "If *I* created the world, I would make it like such and such" shows nothing, because that has no bearing on how G-d creates a world.  And we have no model of how G-d creates worlds to compare our world to.  So the assumption of the question, that if G-d created the world it would be exactly like X, is baseless.

Additionally, R' Lopiansky added that we believe that it is *more* of a revelation of G-d's complete perfection that He can create a world which has so much fragmentation - there is an unveiling of G-d's perfection from within the disparity.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your second paragraph here? Might have an answer in there... :) Thanks! Good stuff otherwise. Put what I was thinking in much better words...

Comment: According to this, wouldn't the intelligent design idea be COMPLETELY useless, even if not being used as a proof in the strictest sense of the word?

Comment: @Gavriel No - despite everything else, the world as it is is an incredible statistical anomaly.  They are two separate points.